# A web page is slowing down your browser, it is waiting for csi.gstatic.com

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, asp.net-mvc-4

I have written web application on .net 2017 c#, I had to change my URL to simpler in order to get rid of ? or = from URL and also I am using Google Map on my web site. When I click to records which will be redirected and changed to other link, I got this error.

Original url is:   mydomain.com/Doctor?id=XX
I converted it to: mydomain.com/Doctor/XX

I did it by defining new MapRoute on RegisterRoutes as:
RouteCofig.cs:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
               "Blog",                                           // Route name
               "Doctor/{id}",                                   // URL with parameters
               new { controller = "Home", action = "PersianDR", id = UrlParameter.Optional }  // Parameter defaults
           );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );
        }
```

I also used angularjs:
Angular Module:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute', 'uiGmapgoogle-maps', 'nemLogging', 'ngSanitize']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeprovider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeprovider.
        when('/Home/PersianDR/:id', {
            templateurl: '/Views/Home/PersianDR.cshtml',
            controller: 'AngularCtrl_ShowDr'
        })
        .
        when('Doctor/:id', {
            redirectto: '/Home/PersianDR/:id'
        })
        .
        otherwise({
             redirectto: '/'
        })
        ;
    //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        rewriteLinks: false
    });
}]);
```

Angular Controller:

```
app.controller("AngularCtrl_ShowDr", function ($scope, $location, angularService_ShowDr, $route, $routeParams, $http, $sce) {
    var docId = $("#myId").val();
 
    $location.path();
    $location.url('Doctor/' + docId).replace();
  
    GetDoctorByID();
    GetGeoCoordinates();
    maps();
});
```

This problem as been started since I changed URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found an interesting answer.
There is a conflict when I wanted to redirect and make my url simple while I am using google map apis, this is because gmap needs absolute path or url while I wanted to change my url simple and elegant.

What I did to remove holding on waiting to load csi.gstatic.com, was to use partial view.

I totally brought my ui-gmap-google-map inside partial view and called it from original one.

In original page.cshtml:

```
 @Html.Partial("_MapDoctor")
```

In partial view , _MapDoctor.cshtml:

```
<div ng-controller="AngularCtrl_MapDr">
    <input type="hidden" id="myId2" value="@ViewBag.id" />
    <ui-gmap-google-map center='mapsdrsec.center' zoom='mapsdrsec.zoom' options='mapsdrsec.options'>
        <ui-gmap-layer type="TrafficLayer" show="mapsdrsec.showTraficLayer"></ui-gmap-layer>
        <ui-gmap-markers models="markers" idkey="markers.id" coords="'coords'">

        </ui-gmap-markers>
    </ui-gmap-google-map>

</div>
```

I wrote specified controller and services in angularjs for partial view. I deleted filling  $scope.map from original and wrote (center, zoom, options, $scope.markers ) in partial view controller.